# form - update the table in php

Tags: php, sql, forms

i have a form and when i press send i want it to update the table,
but it doesnt work, the php update code is in the same page as the form
here is the code:

```
    <button type="submit" name="sumbit"><img src="images/icons/fugue/tick-circle.png" width="16" height="16"> עדכן הזמנה</button>

<?php
con=mysqli_connect("");
mysql_select_db("web2_bestset");


if(isset($_POST['sumbit']))
{
    $add=$_POST['orderStatus'];
    $query="update orders set orderStatus=$add where id=".$order['ID'];
    mysql_query($query) or die("Cannot update");    
}
?>
```

the error that i am getting is : Cannot Update.
how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you checked your error log? What errors do you get? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this? Have you run the query from the command line?

Comment: how about useful errors? `... or die(mysql_error())`. Plus, enjoy having your server pwn3d from the lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) hole

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Not even sure where to be begin... your script is full of problems.  I highly, highly recommend doing some reading up on PHP/MySQL basics before continuing this direction.

Comment: How come you are getting only 1 error here?

Answer (score 0):

Your con has no dollar sign, or is that a typo?

```
$con=mysqli_connect("");
```

And:

```
$query="update orders set orderStatus='".$add."' where id='".$order['ID']."'";
```

Please do keep in mind the others. You will be injected if your not carefull.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your die with this

```
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

And post the error that you are getting?

Comment: Also can you post the syntax of your mysqli_connect()